# Are there any sources that discuss the permissibility of taking delayed release caffeine pills during Ramadan

Tags: ramadan

Just what's in the title. There are pills that have delayed release functions. Can you take such a pill at night so that you can get your daily caffeine.

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: Isn't that breaking your fast?